# measure the number of duplicate calls to web service in asp.net appliction

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance

I have a performance problem in my asp.net application. I want to investigate if I have Unnecessary calls to my web service and how many? I believe that I call to some methods more than once.

How can I check this issue? and is there a tool for visual studio for this kind of issues (for an example feature in visual studio ultimate)?

10x.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the profiler, but, because it does not depend on special tools, why not look at your server's logs?

The server logs will tell you what URLs are requested and from which client. Thus it is easy to see how many calls to each URL (or even, with  a little processing, each folder).

The largest benefit of using server logging is it can be applied to production use.

If this is not enough consider using logging in your application to gather key support information (and this also help support when issues occur on your site).